# Question about proof of: On a normed space E: $\|x\| = \sup\{|l(x)| : l \in E^*, \|l\| \leq 1 \}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Given the following theorem and proof. Can somebody please tell me why equality holds in the equation of the theorem? Why does the existence of one $l \in E^*$ show that the last equality holds for every possible linear operator on E, to me this only implies less than equal and not equality.

[image]

Comment: Side note: in case you were wondering how to obtain the cursive $\ell$, people seem to have all silently agreed to type `$\ell$` rather than just `$l$` in Tex.

Comment: What is shown is 1) for all linear operator $l$ of norm less that $1$, $|l(x)|\leqslant \|x\|$. You can then deduce that the supremum of such $|l(x)|$ is less than $\|x\|$. 2) there exists one particular linear operator $f$ with $\|f\|\leqslant 1$ and $f(x) = \|x\|$. You can then deduce that the supremum of such $|f(x)|$ is greater than $\|x\|$. By 1) and 2), the supremum equals $\|x\|$.